# How to return end-node of a relationship in Cypher-query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Following Cypher-Query returns all relationships from a matching relationship-index:

```
start r=relationship:concept_contained_in_report('concept_id:2') return r
```

How can I return all the end-nodes of those relationships instead of the relationships itself?

I would expect something like

```
 start r=relationship:concept_contained_in_report('concept_id:2') return r.end
```

but that doesn't work since end (the endnode) is not a property of relationship.

Thanks
Jorg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
start r=relationship:concept_contained_in_report('concept_id:2')
match ()-[r]->endNode
return endNode
```

Basically, match the relationship with its beginning and end. You don't care about the beginning, so don't assign it an identifier. Assign an identifier to the end node and return it.

Answer (score 1):

or in Neo4j 2.0+, you may also try the following code:

```
start r=relationship:concept_contained_in_report('concept_id:2')
return endNode(r) as eNode
```

they provide a very convenient feature, eh.

Comment: Is it possible to return only endNodes that match a specific label? I don't want all endNodes but only those that have a specific label.